# Предложение об увеличении количества голосов за закрытие

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, модерация, закрытие-вопросов

Меня и некоторый честной народ совершенно не устраивает столь малое количество голосов за закрытие. Даже при небольшой активности очереди, голоса заканчиваются очень быстро. Буквально за один раз можно всё потратить, а ожидать 20 часов — слишком долго, выходит КПД очень сомнительный.

Поэтому прошу либо снизить время ожидания (до часа?), либо давать больше голосов.

Comment: проблема не в количестве голосов. проблема в малом количестве закрывающих и в большом количестве накопившегося мусора.

Comment: Да какая разница? Факт один - не хватает на проверку голосов. Причина не так важна, ибо повлиять на количество проверяющих или мусора никто не может.

Comment: А может быть, просто надо поменьше удалять? Я не вижу достаточных причин для повышения предела в тексте вопроса (кроме «мне лично хочется»).

Comment: @TheDoctor закончились голоса за удаление? минусуй! минусы к вопросам бесплатные :)

Comment: Давайте отвечайте, а не комментируйте.
Поменьше удалять - не вариант, мусора-то много.
Минусовать тоже вообще не вариант - новорегам или "идиотам" чихать на репу и просьбы перестать клепать вопросы "Памагите, решите за меня и отправьте декану с письменными извинениями за задержку!".

Comment: Отвечу вечером.

Comment: Судя по всему, большинство не согласно с тем, что мусора **слишком** много. Если незакрытые вопросы будут реально, не на словах мешать сообществу, думаю, активных удаляторов прибавится.

Comment: Да большинство и не отписалось :)

Comment: IMHO все эти закрытия и удаления -- просто дурь (и абсолютно неважно, что она унаследована от SO). Наверное поэтому большинство посещающих форум этим и не занимаются. Т.е. на самом деле простое правило -- *не нравится вопрос, пройди мимо* -- действует.

Comment: Мне кажется, это синдром вахтёра.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю наоборот уменьшить количество голосов за закрытие.

Тогда, возможно, у участников останется больше времени для созидательной работы. Приведение вопросов трёхлетней давности к стандартам английского SO созидательной работой не является.