# Как насчет уменьшения количества голосов для закрывашек?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, очередь-проверок, закрытие-вопросов

Автобот поднял связанный вопрос [Как насчет того, чтобы увеличить число голосов за закрытие?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5) Так вот, как насчет того, чтобы наоборот уменьшить число этих голосов? Закрывашками занимается на регулярной основе ОЧЕНЬ ограниченное подмножество участников. Это приводит к тому, что закрывание вопросов по факту доверено ограниченному кругу лиц. В идеале этим должно заниматься "сообщество", что бы это ни значило. Я вкладываю в это определение в данном контексте количественный смысл - закрывашками должны заниматься не 10 человек, а много более, чтобы исключить фактор систематической ошибки (чтобы регулярные закрывальщики не закрывали массово среднего качества вопросы и у них был шанс выкарабкаться). Если больше никто этим не занимается - значит проблема не велика и вместо закрытия вопрос нужно отредактировать, оставить комментарий, поставить минус, если ничего не помогает и пятерка минусов вполне красноречиво будет говорить о качестве вопроса/ответа и, возможно, вопрос/ответ будет удален автоматически. Также то, что закрытием заведует малый круг лиц приводит к тому, что переоткрыть вопрос почти невозможно - переоткрытиями занимаются те же самые, кто и закрыл вопрос (круговая порука в чистом виде).

Как результат я не думаю, что уютненький заполнится и потонет в "мусорных" вопросах - просто критерий мусорности сдвинется в сторону и закрываться будут только совсем уж неадекватные вопросы/ответы.

Также, возможно, раз у тех, кто занимается очередью есть время на закрытие , то найдется равное количество времени на редактирование/помощь/наводящие вопросы?

Comment: Автоботы... десептиконы

Comment: Не кажется ли несколько парадоксальным публиковать на мете такой вопрос, где, собственно, участники как раз из упомянутой группы? Это как на собрании топ менеджеров поднимать вопрос о сокращении премий топ менеджерам )

Comment: Эм.. Пока я ответ не прочитал, вообще не понимал, что предлагается в вопросе...

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, это совершенно правильное место. Возможно закрывашки хотя бы задумаются...

Comment: `В идеале этим должно заниматься "сообщество", что бы это ни значило` — этим занимается всякий, имеющий выше двух тысяч баллов репутации. При наличии желания, разумеется.

Comment: @Arhad трёх тысяч

Answer (score 4):

Не так давно мы увеличили количество голосов *за закрытие и повторное открытие* вопросов с 24 до 50. Причиной этому является большое количество вопросов в очереди (на данный момент это 187 вопросов).

Как мне кажется, имеет место недоразумение в связи с выбранной терминологией. Участник может отдать 50 голосов не только для закрытия вопросов, но и за то, чтобы оставить открытыми вопросы, попавшими в очередь на закрытие. Таким образом, увеличение количества голосов не должно привести к большему количеству закрытых вопросов, но к уменьшению длинны очереди, то есть к большей скорости предоставления отзыва от сообщества конкретному участнику о качестве/тематичности заданного вопроса.

См. также:

- [Что такое очередь проверок и как она работает?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4912/)

Comment: *Участник может отдать 50 голосов не только для закрытия вопросов, но и за то, чтобы оставить открытыми вопросы, попавшими в очередь на закрытие.* — насколько я вижу — это не так. в очереди и **вне её** можно проголосовать **за закрытие** 50 раз. а вот за **не**закрытие можно проголосовать только в очереди, «длина» которой осталась прежней — 20 проверок в сутки.

Answer (score -5):

Не надо понижать количество закрывашек. Какая разница сколько их? Проблема ведь не в их количестве, а, как я понял, в том, что не хватает людей, которые могут помочь с проверкой тревог.

Значит решать нужно эту проблему, а не предпринимать костыльные решения, дабы пофиксить неприятные мелочи. Вы крупного и родительского бага не видите, который стоило бы разрешить и который разрешил бы и эту, и многие другие проблемы, как наследственные: **`Сообщество не лояльно, агрессивно, нелогично и шаблонно: даже если опционально лучший ответ чей-то другой, участники голосуют за те ответы, авторы которых имеют больше репутации.`**

Нужно перестроить шаблон поведения, ввести культуру, так сказать, понять почему сообщество так себя ведёт, как так к этому пришло... И нужно, как минимум, вести себя более лояльно к тем, кто старается активно заработать репутацию, выйти в топ, к тем, кто преследует цель стать модератором, ну или хотя бы заработать как можно больше топовых привилегий.

Comment: Первый абзац и предложение сразу за ним по делу, с ними согласен. От уменьшения числа закрывашек объёмы очередей скорее увеличатся, т. к. людей больше не станет, а у тех кто уже очередями занимается станет меньше "запас хода", и в итоге темпы разгребания упадут. А вот о перестроении культуры хотелось бы услышать подробнее. У вас есть конкретные предложения на этот счёт?

Comment: @D-side конкретного предложения на данный момент нет. Я не так давно тут (и месяца нет), так что мне пока рано выдвигать какую-то стратегию. Есть видение, но плана нет. Хотя даже за 3 дня можно увидеть не вооружённым взглядом, что менталитет тут чисто восточно-европейский: люди сами не думают, много попрошайничают, вопросы одни и те же. Сложные вопросы минусуют, а помогают по факту одни и те же. Очень часто топовые агрессоры, заходя в тупик, апеллируют к авторитетам вместо того, чтобы самим аргументировать свою позицию (типичная черта глупых людей) и т.д., т.п.

Comment: @KitScribe опять вы без доказательств обвинениями кидаетесь

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov очевидные вещи доказательств не требуют. Не хотите видеть проблему и предпочитаете игнорировать её пока кто-нибудь не опровергнет все ваши аргументы в защиту того, что всё хорошо - ваше право. Только: 1. Если вы хотите видеть сообщество по-своему, то вы и будете его таким видеть, и даже на 1000 аргументов вы найдёте 1001 контраргумент. И  2: Вряд ли найдётся хоть кто-то, кому интересно будет решать такую задачу, потому что мне уже пофиг и на ruSO, и на его будущее

Comment: @KitScribe я хочу видеть не "сообщество по-своему", а правду. А вы ее от меня уже кучу времени скрываете. Что и заставляет предположить что правды у вас нет.

Comment: можно ссылку на не *до оцененный ответ*, кину *плюсик* если это действительно так, иначе кину *минус* вашему *посту*

Comment: *1. Если вы хотите видеть сообщество по-своему, то вы и будете его таким видеть, и даже на 1000 аргументов вы найдёте 1001 контраргумент.* данное утверждение может быть применено и к Вам в частности. если Вы хотите видеть что все плохо то так оно для Вас и будет. я же считаю иначе. проблемы есть но идеального решения не существует

Comment: `Очень часто топовые агрессоры, заходя в тупик..... вместо того, чтобы самим аргументировать свою позицию (типичная черта глупых людей) и т.д., т.п. – Kit Scribe 11 часов назад` ............. `очевидные вещи доказательств не требуют. – Kit Scribe 1 час назад ` - я так понимаю вы только что признали себя агрессором и притом не очень умным. забавно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я не считаю себя агрессором. И непонятна ваша логика: разве я апеллировал к авторитетам?

Comment: @KitScribe при захвате территории, убийстве невинных людей все агрессоры считают, что они лишь расширяют владения.... то что вы не считаете себя таковым не значит, что вы им не являетесь....... и да - вы вообще никак не апеллируете, лишь балаболите и не можете аргументировать вообще ничего....и это, как вы сами сказали - `типичная черта глупых людей`.

Comment: @Bald спасибо! Я надеялся, что кто-то выскажет такой аргумент, и специально для этого сделал такую формулировку. Хоть это и не самый лучший пример будет, но он сойдёт для понимания, если не совсем всё плохо... **Одна из причин низкого количества активных участников, малого количества хороших участников - большое количество занудных участников: людей, которые придираются к мелочам, минусуют из-за малейшей невзрачной ерунды и т.д.** Одно из предложений - начать с себя и начать ставить больше плюсов, стать более вежливыми, более лояльными и уступчивыми

Comment: @PavelMayorov правду я от вас и не скрываю, задумайтесь над происходящим, поразмышляйте что не так и всё станет очевидно. Или вы хотите, чтобы я пост написал?

Comment: @KitScribe, `... участники голосуют за те ответы, авторы которых имеют больше репутации` — **в большинстве случаев высокореповые участники дают *развёрнутый и исчерпывающий* ответ, за что и получают плюсы.**

Comment: @KitScribe, И ещё. Согласен, что **есть** необоснованно минусующие участники. Однако SO **уже пытается противодействовать** этому. Во-первых, **один плюс перебивает** своими баллами сразу несколько минусов. Во-вторых, работает **закон больших чисел** — необоснованные минуса попросту потонут под шквалом обоснованных плюсов (и наоборот).

Comment: @KitScribe и после этого вы говорите, что вам всё равно. Очень неубедительно. Вы можете не считать себя агрессором, но судя по минусам и комментариям, вас именно так и восприняли. А вы даже не удосуживаетесь подкреплять свою позицию конкретными примерами, якобы потому, что проблема очевидна. Если она очевидна, то предоставить примеры не составит для вас труда. А без них дискуссия продолжит в лучшем случае топтаться на месте, в худшем -- скатываться во флейм (что уже началось). А поскольку кроме вас эту проблему пока никто публично не признал, примеры за вами.